# Html Css e Php conteúdo Dinâmico em DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site e nele criei uma área de serviços onde através de CSS, HTML, PHP e Laravel exibo o conteúdo de forma dinâmica, faço um foreach...

Como não limito quantos registros o usuário pode incluir ele consegue incluir quantos quiser o que me gera um problema de Layout quando ele não inclui de 3 em 3, vejam na imagem ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, só existe 4 registros cadastrados sendo que o ultimo ficou na parte de baixo da tela o que acabou gerando um espaço em branco na direita.

Por isso pergunto: 
Como faço para ajustar? existe alguma forma de obter através de javascript o tamanho do espaço em branco para que eu consiga ajudar a Box via CSS?

Codigo do HTML / Blade

```
   <section class="servicos">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row text-center">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;S e r v i c o s </h2>
                    <hr>
             </div> 
        </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="container">                     
                  @forelse($servicos as $dados_servicos)
                    <div class="col-xs-4">                                
                            <div class="box col-xs-12">                     
                                  <div class="icone text-center">    
                                      <i class="fa {{$dados_servicos->caminhoicone}} fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
                                  </div>                                     
                                 <h3 class="text-center titulo">{{$dados_servicos->titulo}} </h3>
                                 <p class="texto">{!!$dados_servicos->post!!}  </p>                                     
                            </div>                                              
                    </div>
                    @empty
                    Nenhum Serviço Cadastrado
                    @endforelse            
                </div>
           </div>

        </section>
```

CSS

```
.servicos .box{

    border-radius: 3%;
    text-align: center;  
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:#a09f9d;
    font-family: "Roboto-Light";
    float: left;
    /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);*/
    cursor: pointer;


}

.servicos .box:hover{  
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
}



.servicos .box .icone{
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;

}

.servicos .box .titulo{

    color:white;
    font-family: "Roboto-Light";
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;

}


.servicos .box .texto{
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Roboto-Light";
    color: white;   
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Diego vc quer mantar o tamanho do Box Cinza e centralizar ele na página, ou vc quer que ele "Espiche" e ocupe 100% do espaço em branco restante?

Comment: @hugocsl, se for um único registro eu pretendo centralizar, mas pode acontecer casos de ter 2 registros também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jovem segue uma resposta que pode te ajudar. Vc vai ter que misturar o Grid do Bootstrap com Flex-box.

Mexi muito pouco no CSS e no HTML, mas precisai fazer alguma coisa... Basta vc dar uma olhada pq deixei as coisas comentadas no CSS

Com isso mesmo só tento 1 ou 2 itens na linha de baixo eles sempre estarão no meio da página preste atenção nessas classes, pois elas que fazem a "magica" acontecer

```
.holder {
        /* essas são as classes de alinhamento dos boxes dentro do container */
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        max-width: 970px; /* aqui vc define a largura máxima, no caso fiz para caber apenas 3 boxes, e conforme for diminuindo a tela vai ficar 2 por linha e finalmente 1 por linha. */
}
```

***Veja abaixo o Exemplo funcionando! Exiba em "Página toda" para ver melhor a resposividade.***

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .col-box {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px 2px; /* aqui é o tamanho da borda entre um box e outro, depende vc vai ter que fazer ajustes finos para te atender melhor */
        }
        .holder {
            /* essas são as classes de alinhamento dos boxes dentro do container */
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            max-width: 970px; /* aqui vc define a largura máxima, no caso fiz para caber apenas 3 boxes, e conforme for diminuindo a tela vai ficar 2 por linha e finalmente 1 por linha. */
        }
        
        .servicos .box{
        border-radius: 3%;
        text-align: center;  
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color:#a09f9d;
        font-family: "Roboto-Light";
        /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);*/
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        .servicos .box:hover{  
        box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        transition: all 1.0s ease;
        }
        .servicos .box .icone{
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: white;
        }
        .servicos .box .titulo{
        color:white;
        font-family: "Roboto-Light";
        overflow: hidden;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        .servicos .box .texto{
        position: relative;
        font-family: "Roboto-Light";
        color: white;   
        margin-top: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<section class="servicos">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <h2>
                        <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;S e r v i c o s </h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @forelse($servicos as $dados_servicos)
        
                <div class="container holder">
        
                    <div class="col-box">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icone text-center">
                                <i class="fa {{$dados_servicos->caminhoicone}} fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-center titulo">{{$dados_servicos->titulo}} </h3>
                            <p class="texto">{!!$dados_servicos->post!!} </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-box">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icone text-center">
                                <i class="fa {{$dados_servicos->caminhoicone}} fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-center titulo">{{$dados_servicos->titulo}} </h3>
                            <p class="texto">{!!$dados_servicos->post!!} </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-box">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icone text-center">
                                <i class="fa {{$dados_servicos->caminhoicone}} fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-center titulo">{{$dados_servicos->titulo}} </h3>
                            <p class="texto">{!!$dados_servicos->post!!} </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-box">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icone text-center">
                                <i class="fa {{$dados_servicos->caminhoicone}} fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-center titulo">{{$dados_servicos->titulo}} </h3>
                            <p class="texto">{!!$dados_servicos->post!!} </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-box">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icone text-center">
                                <i class="fa {{$dados_servicos->caminhoicone}} fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-center titulo">{{$dados_servicos->titulo}} </h3>
                            <p class="texto">{!!$dados_servicos->post!!} </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
        
                    <!-- @empty Nenhum Serviço Cadastrado @endforelse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </section>
```

Comment: hugocsl obrigado amigo!!! Funcionou perfeitamente!!! era realmente isso  que precisava! não conhecia a propriedade Flex, valeu pela dica e ajuda!!! abraços